# Does Transmission Bittorrent client use UDP?

Tags: bittorrent, udp, denial-of-service

I am running a Transmission Bittorent server to upload various Linux ISOs.

I am currently being flooded by UDP packets. I mean the DoS protection in the Archer C5 home router and it blocks parts of my home network.

I am unsure if I even need to have the UDP port open for the Transmission daemon to accept incoming connections correctly.

So my first question is, **does Transmission Bittorrent client even use UDP?**

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BitTorrent#Security_problems

Comment: http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0041.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Transmission uses both TCP (standard BitTorrent) and UDP (BitTorrent over [µTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micro_Transport_Protocol)).